# Using unicode variables in Scala tuple assignment

Tags: scala, unicode, naming-conventions

```
val ©® = 1
val (©, ®) = (1, 2)
```

Line 1 works fine in both Scalac and the REPL but line 2 chokes on both.

Is this a bug? Or is there a special syntax that I'm missing?

Disclaimer: I know that using non-ASCII variable names is a terrible idea. I came across this by complete accident. My codebase isn't full of wacky symbols, I swear. Please don't lynch me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
scala> val (x, y) = (1, 2)
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 2

scala> val (X, Y) = (1, 2)
<console>:7: error: not found: value X
       val (X, Y) = (1, 2)
            ^
<console>:7: error: not found: value Y
       val (X, Y) = (1, 2)
               ^
```

What happens is that unicode is treated like uppercase characters when it comes to pattern matching, which means that, since it "starts" with an "uppercase letter", it thinks you are comparing to a constant instead of assigning values.

Another example:

```
val © = 1
val ® = 3

(1, 2) match {
  case (©, ®) => "Both match"
  case (_, ®) => "Second matches"
  case (©, _) => "First matches"
  case _      => "None match"
}
```

results in

```
res0: java.lang.String = First matches
```

Comment: It's actually defined conversely, "a variable pattern starts with a lower case letter." I suppose it's a bug that '_' is taken as lower case, but maybe they want that. BTW, I think the official policy is that wacky symbols are fine when deployed in the service of ASCII art. Or, in this case, non-ASCII art.

Comment: @som-snytt What's upper or lower case is defined in the spec. Does spec define _ as upper case but the compiler treat it as lower?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I wonder would it be grotesque if Scala 3 used `$x` for pattern vars. At some point, current behavior stopped being cool.